# Multi-byte string cutter - performance tuning

Tags: php, performance

I have a news site that is written in Greek.

In my home page I have to show each story's title plus some characters of the story's content.

I want to cut the story's content at the end the last word that fits the character limit I have set.

I have achieved this by using some multi-byte safe functions and combining them, but it seems to be extremely performance expensive, since it costs me around 150ms for a page that without cutting the strings can load in less than 10ms.

So I am wondering. Is there a way to performance tune the functions below AND keep them multi-byte safe, or should I just accept them as they are?

```
// multibyte wordcutter
function cutString( $string , $width = 20 , $cut=false ){
    if( mb_strlen( $string , "UTF-8" ) == 0 ){
        return $string;
        }
    $input = $string;
    if ( mb_strlen( $string , "UTF-8" ) > $width ) {
        $string = mb_wordwrap( $string , $width , "\n" , $cut );
        $string = mb_substr( $string , 0 , mb_strpos( $string , "\n" , NULL , "UTF-8" ) , "UTF-8" );
        if( mb_strlen( $string , "UTF-8" ) > $width ) {
            $string = mb_wordwrap( $string , $width , "\n" , true );
            $string = mb_substr( $string , 0 , mb_strpos( $string , "\n" , NULL , "UTF-8" ) , "UTF-8" );
            }
        elseif( mb_strlen( $string , "UTF-8" ) == 0 ){
            $string = mb_wordwrap( $input , $width , "\n" , true );
            $string = mb_substr( $string , 0 , mb_strpos( $string , "\n" , NULL , "UTF-8" ) , "UTF-8" );
            }
        }
    return $string;
    }

// multibyte safe wordwrap
function mb_wordwrap($string, $width = 75, $break = "\n", $cut = false, $charset = 'utf-8')
{
    $stringWidth = iconv_strlen($string, $charset);
    $breakWidth  = iconv_strlen($break, $charset);

    if (strlen($string) === 0) {
        return '';
    } elseif ($breakWidth === null) {
        throw new Zend_Text_Exception('Break string cannot be empty');
    } elseif ($width === 0 && $cut) {
        throw new Zend_Text_Exception('Can\'t force cut when width is zero');
    }

    $result    = '';
    $lastStart = $lastSpace = 0;

    for ($current = 0; $current < $stringWidth; $current++) {
        $char = mb_substr($string, $current, 1, $charset);

        if ($breakWidth === 1) {
            $possibleBreak = $char;
        } else {
            $possibleBreak = mb_substr($string, $current, $breakWidth, $charset);
        }

        if ($possibleBreak === $break) {
            $result    .= mb_substr($string, $lastStart, $current - $lastStart + $breakWidth, $charset);
            $current   += $breakWidth - 1;
            $lastStart  = $lastSpace = $current + 1;
        } elseif ($char === ' ') {
            if ($current - $lastStart >= $width) {
                $result    .= mb_substr($string, $lastStart, $current - $lastStart, $charset) . $break;
                $lastStart  = $current + 1;
            }

            $lastSpace = $current;
        } elseif ($current - $lastStart >= $width && $cut && $lastStart >= $lastSpace) {
            $result    .= mb_substr($string, $lastStart, $current - $lastStart, $charset) . $break;
            $lastStart  = $lastSpace = $current;
        } elseif ($current - $lastStart >= $width && $lastStart < $lastSpace) {
            $result    .= mb_substr($string, $lastStart, $lastSpace - $lastStart, $charset) . $break;
            $lastStart  = $lastSpace = $lastSpace + 1;
        }
    }

    if ($lastStart !== $current) {
        $result .= mb_substr($string, $lastStart, $current - $lastStart, $charset);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**EDIT: This is what I ended up using**

```
// multibyte wordcutter
function cutString( $string , $width = 70 , $cut=false ){
    $string = mb_substr( $string , 0 , $width , "UTF-8" );
    if( mb_strlen( $string , "UTF-8" ) < $width ){
        return $string;
        }
    $dot = mb_strripos( $string , '.' , 0 , "UTF-8" ) + 1;
    $space = mb_strripos( $string , ' ' , 0 , "UTF-8" );
    if( $space ){
        if( ($space-$dot) < 20 ){
            $string = mb_substr( $string , 0 , $dot , "UTF-8" );
            }
        else {
            $string = mb_substr( $string , 0 , $space , "UTF-8" );
            }
        }
    return $string;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to measure how much this function execution exactly takes? I don't believe it's 140ms and I'm sure you've just measured it wrong.

Comment: Sadly I am 100% sure. 150ms for cutting 5 stories, each story around 2-3k characters.

Comment: Well... I don't think the problem is introduced by the multibyte functions, but the actual sunstringing + searching of such big strings. I'm thinking that if you test with regular string functions (not mb_), you'd get similar results.

Comment: @AnPel: what exactly do you want to achieve? It's a bit complicated to read your code. The current issue is caused by the only loop in `mb_wordwrap` function.

Comment: @zerkms: he stated pretty clearly: "Is there a way to performance tune the functions below AND keep them multi-byte safe, or should I just accept them as they are?". He'd like better execution speed.

Comment: @Alexandru Mihai: I asked about the task. Without clear explanation of what code is supposed to do - it's too tricky to find it out by reading that tangled code.

Comment: "Accept them as they are because I can't see a way to make things run any faster" would be a perfectly acceptable answer, if that is your opinion.

Comment: @AnPel: it's not an option. Your code obviously is **FAR** from ideal and I'm sure the `mb_wordwrap` may be optimized much, but the detailed explanation of the cutting logic is required.

Comment: @zerkms mb_wordwrap is self explanatory. As for cutString, I want to provide a string and a width and return a string that is cut to the last word that can fit in the width.

Comment: @AnPel: why do you iterate from the first character then? Cut by the required length and reduce to nearest space from the end. So only one `mb_substr` is required in a loop body, followed by a `break`

Comment: wordwrap breaks the string to lines using '\n', then with substr I keep only the first line.

Comment: @AnPel: that is why I asked about detailed requirements. Well, it's up to you - to provide an explanation or wait for someone to read your inefficient spaghetti.

Comment: @zerkms now that is an excellent answer, please form it as one so I can award reputation.

Comment: It's not an answer. Your code may be rewritten in much more efficient manner. Currently it's terribly inefficient with a lot of pointless loops with pointless `mb_substr`. To rewrite it in a proper way - the detailed requirements should be provided.

Comment: @zerkms It's not that I don't want to provide more details. All I want is to cut the string in a multibyte safe way to the last word so that it does fit a required width. If the first word is longer than the width, then just cut the word. that is pretty much everything, so what you told above is perfection.

Comment: @AnPel: so the obvious algorithm is: to cut by the required length, then loop back char by char checking if it's a space. Then perform cut. That easy

Comment: @zerkms it is indeed, but after someone points out the obvious thing causing the big load! So since you helped me see a much faster way to do it, I asked for an answer so I can rep you for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current implementation is overcomplicated.

If I understood right then the better strategy would be:

1. Cut the string by the length
2. Iterate over characters from the end up to the first space
3. Break and return the result

It should improve the performance significantly.

Comment: I'm done writing, I made it cut to the last sentence ending if it's close enough too, no calls to mb_wordwrap, mb_substr and mb_strripos did the trick just fine. Page load time from 160ms now is 5.7ms. Big thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a real test case and xdebug to check performance.
2. I tested with this code:

// test page

```
<?php

    $strSmall = "ये एक हिन्दी वाक्य है, इसमे बहुत सारे शब्द हैं |";
    $strBig = implode(".",array_fill(0,100,$strSmall));  // Create a big string

    $tStart = microtime(true);
    echo cutString($strBig);
    $tEnd = microtime(true);

    echo "\nTime taken:" , ($tEnd - $tStart) , " s";

    // multibyte wordcutter
    function cutString( $string , $width = 20 , $cut=false ){
        if( mb_strlen( $string , "UTF-8" ) == 0 ){
            return $string;
            }
        $input = $string;
        if ( mb_strlen( $string , "UTF-8" ) > $width ) {
            $string = mb_wordwrap( $string , $width , "\n" , $cut );
            $string = mb_substr( $string , 0 , mb_strpos( $string , "\n" , NULL , "UTF-8" ) , "UTF-8" );
            if( mb_strlen( $string , "UTF-8" ) > $width ) {
                $string = mb_wordwrap( $string , $width , "\n" , true );
                $string = mb_substr( $string , 0 , mb_strpos( $string , "\n" , NULL , "UTF-8" ) , "UTF-8" );
                }
            elseif( mb_strlen( $string , "UTF-8" ) == 0 ){
                $string = mb_wordwrap( $input , $width , "\n" , true );
                $string = mb_substr( $string , 0 , mb_strpos( $string , "\n" , NULL , "UTF-8" ) , "UTF-8" );
                }
            }
        return $string;
        }




  // multibyte safe wordwrap
function mb_wordwrap($string, $width = 75, $break = "\n", $cut = false, $charset = 'utf-8')
{

$stringWidth = iconv_strlen($string, $charset);
$breakWidth  = iconv_strlen($break, $charset);

    if (strlen($string) === 0) {
        return '';
    } elseif ($breakWidth === null) {
        throw new Zend_Text_Exception('Break string cannot be empty');
    } elseif ($width === 0 && $cut) {
        throw new Zend_Text_Exception('Can\'t force cut when width is zero');
    }

    $result    = '';
    $lastStart = $lastSpace = 0;

    for ($current = 0; $current < $stringWidth; $current++) {
        $char = mb_substr($string, $current, 1, $charset);

        if ($breakWidth === 1) {
            $possibleBreak = $char;
        } else {
            $possibleBreak = mb_substr($string, $current, $breakWidth, $charset);
        }

        if ($possibleBreak === $break) {
            $result    .= mb_substr($string, $lastStart, $current - $lastStart + $breakWidth,charset);
            $current   += $breakWidth - 1;
            $lastStart  = $lastSpace = $current + 1;
        } elseif ($char === ' ') {
            if ($current - $lastStart >= $width) {
                $result    .= mb_substr($string, $lastStart, $current - $lastStart, $charset) . $break;
                $lastStart  = $current + 1;
            }

            $lastSpace = $current;
        } elseif ($current - $lastStart >= $width && $cut && $lastStart >= $lastSpace) {
            $result    .= mb_substr($string, $lastStart, $current - $lastStart, $charset) . $break;
            $lastStart  = $lastSpace = $current;
        } elseif ($current - $lastStart >= $width && $lastStart < $lastSpace) {
            $result    .= mb_substr($string, $lastStart, $lastSpace - $lastStart, $charset) . $break;
            $lastStart  = $lastSpace = $lastSpace + 1;
        }
    }

    if ($lastStart !== $current) {
        $result .= mb_substr($string, $lastStart, $current - $lastStart, $charset);
    }
    return $result;
}

?>
```

3. It took around 200 ms.

   Performance Test
   ये एक हिन्दी वाक्य
   Time taken:0.23847889900208 s
4. This is xdebug profiling result, you can see that `iconv_strlen` and `mb_substr` are eating the time :

[image]

. Instead of so many function calls to make the code easy, try to minimize function calls, and write some own loops.